# Populate columns of table with other table that doesn't have relationship

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-9.3

Hello I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL: the 1st one

```sql
"Products" 
id
price
factor1
factor2
```

the columns factor1 and factor2 they both are empty and I want to populate them with the data of another table

```sql
"Article" 
id
factor1
factor2
```

I want to populate the columns where the id of Product is the same as the Article but the tables doesn't have a relationship to each other or FK so how can I accomplish this?

I've tried this:

```sql
UPDATE Products
SET factor1 =
  (SELECT factor1
   FROM Article
   WHERE Article.id = Products.id)
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT factor1
   FROM Article
   WHERE Article.factor1 = Products.id)
```

but I get this error:

> SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "Article" does not exist
>     Position: 213

Comment: works for me.  Or at least, doesn't give the error you indicate, as long as the table "article" does exist, but I doubt it does what you want since you have two different where clauses.

Comment: @jjanes you think it might be a DBeaver error?

Comment: I doubt it. It looks just like a PostgreSQL error which dbeaver is passing along to you.  It could be that dbeaver is setting your search_path in such a way that "article" can't be found.  Can you run the statement in psql to take dbeaver out of the loop and see what happens?

Comment: `"Article"` is a different name then `Article` - the error message indicates you used `"Article"` not `Article` as the code in your question does

Answer (score 1):

As @a_horse_with_no_name has pointed out in comments:

> "Article" is a different name then Article

A fiddle with you current table names & query:

[Example Using double-quoted names](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e980de42cb5ff32576086d5c11f4037c)

Returns your error:

> ERROR:  relation "products" does not exist LINE 1:
>   UPDATE Products

But if you un-quote it:

[Example without double-quoting names](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fa24d9b691716e4ea48752acac251859)

it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The more compact way to write this would be:

```
UPDATE Products
SET factor1 = article.factor1
from Article
WHERE Article.id = Products.id and products.factor1 is null
```

Comment: can you explain the where clause why products.factor1 is null ?

Comment: The IS NULL is just to not update it if it is already populated.  If you are certain the column is completely empty, or want to overwrite them even if they are already populated, you can leave that part out.